# how to prove following statements using Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: isabelle, first-order-logic

Can anyone please help me to prove `X=M` using the following set of the equation(first-order logic)in Isabelle/HOL?

```
N>=M

forall n. 0=<n<N --> n<M

X=N
```

where `N, M, X` are integers constant. `n` integer variable.. '-->' stands for implies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof can only be done if the variables are *naturals*, not integers, e.g. using this proof:

```
theory Scratch
imports Main
begin
theorem
  fixes N M X :: nat
  assumes "N ≥ M"
  assumes "∀ n. (0 ≤ n ∧ n < N) ⟶ n<M"
  assumes "X = N"
  shows "X = M"
proof-
  have "¬ N > M"
  proof
    assume "M < N" with `∀ n. _` show False by auto
  qed
  with `N ≥ M` and `X = N`
  show "X = M" by auto
qed

end
```

If you allow integers than a counter-example wold be `M=-2`, `N=-1` and `X=-2`.

Comment: thanks a lot. One more question if the property is X=N^3, then we need to define power. Can you please guide me in this regards.

Comment: You can write `N ^ 3` for powers, I think.